# How to apply SVG clip path relative to origin SVG instead of target element

Tags: javascript, css, svg, clip-path

I am trying to apply an SVG `clipPath` to a separate background `div` which has fixed positioning. I would like the `clip-path` to remain at the exact location of the origin SVG element, and to accordingly move when scrolling (or otherwise transformed).

What is happening instead, is that the clip path is inserted relative to the target element's origin and loses all positioning, scrolling, and transforms. Is there a way to preserve origin properties and apply these to a separate div?

In the embedded snippet below, the blue circle is where I would like the `clip-path` to be, whereas the red circle is where it is showing up.

```css
#container {
  clip-path: url(#myClip);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}

#offset-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>

</div>

<div id='offset-container'>
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="myClip">
      <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fill='blue' fill-opacity='0.5'/>
</svg>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/shongololo/pa0qLs45/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works (almost) in Firefox, but not in Chrome, where it shows a really strange bug.

You'll need two divs: The outer is positioned relative and defines the clip-path so it moves. The inner is positioned fixed. Apparently, the explicit setting of top/left/width/height is needed and then refers to viewport coordinates.

```css
body { margin: 0 }

#container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 202px; /* border! */
  left: 202px;
  clip-path: url(#myClip);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}

#offset-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
    <div id="fixed"></div>
</div>

<div id='offset-container'>
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="myClip">
      <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fill='blue' fill-opacity='0.5'/>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Very interesting. Weird bug indeed in Chrome. Safari seems to ignore the clip path altogether!